# Use of conditional sentence?

Tags: grammar, conditionals, construction, grammaticality

Oh, I'm not sad. I made sure I've got a lotta dreams, so if one breaks, I can/could pursue another.

**Should I follow up with can or could after the "if" clause?**

Comment: I would say "can".

Answer (score 2):

..."so if one breaks, I can pursue another" is correct because there is continuity of time from the present to the future. There are multiple uses of could. But in this setting, "could" is parallel to "would", whose context is appropriate when referring to the future of the past, not transitioning through the present.

To use "could", one option of the sentence formulation "could" be:

"Oh, I was not sad. I made sure I got lotta dreams, so if one broke, I could pursue another."